# Custom permalink for wordpress page / post

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages

I want to set a custom permalink for a specific wordpress page/post.

My expectation: 
1) Go to specific wordpress page/post edit view.
2) Click edit permalink.
3) Type in new permalink for the specific page/post and click save.

I have found a plugin name [Custom Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks) which fits the exact need.
However, it seems not working in my environment (wordpress 4.8.x). When i use the new custom permalinks it display error 404.

Did i miss out any settings?

Note that if i use the custom permalink available by wordpress itself (which does not fit my needs), it works.

Any idea of how to have custom permalink for specific page/post.

Answer (score 0):

You to be sure: after editing the permalink you first have to click at the `ok`button and then update the post as well. Don't know if you did that. After doing that it might help to go to setting/ permalinks and press the blue update button (I don't know the button label in english version..)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to updated the post by clicking Publish button. Once you publish the post your custom permalink will get active.

Note:

1. This feature is also available with the Yoast SEO Plugin. So, in case if you are using Yoast then there is no need of addttional Plugin for this.
2. Please ensure you have made proper redirect after changing the permalink. Otherwise it will give 303 error for the old links.